# Change the language of the home/user/ folders automatically

Tags: directory, home-directory, language-support

When I changed my language/locale settings, a window popped up asking me if I wanted to rename Documents, Music, Video, Downloads, to the new language.

I was worried that this might be some irreversible operation and said no and ticked the don't ask me again box.

Now I want the system to change the folders name automatically when I switch to another language automatically. Is there a way to do this? or to make the popping window appear again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you told it to not ask you again, it probably removed the file

```
~/.config/user-dirs.locale
```

You can re-create that file. Assuming that the folders currently have English names, open a terminal window and run:

```
echo 'en_US' > ~/.config/user-dirs.locale
```

Comment: thank you so much! i was looking for this for two weeks :)

Comment: @AlKaef: You're welcome. I noticed that this seems to be more or less undocumented.

Comment: LANG=C xdg-user-dirs-update --force ; cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs

Answer (score 11):

The popping window will show itself if you will change language again. You can use `xprop` command to get this window's name.

To update folder locations after you renamed/moved them, you have to edit `.config/user-dirs.dirs` and put there new folder locations.

And, finally, you have to run `xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update` or `xdg-user-dirs-update`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Raspbian 10), both config files were wrong, so I deleted both:

```
rm ~/.config/user-dirs.{dirs,locale}
```

And after a relogin, they were recreated correctly. Problem solved.